# VueJS grid multi checkbox with dynamic v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a grid of selectable checkboxes using a dynamic `v-model`.

I think it doesn't need too much an explanation.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dacastro4/djekvawm/) demonstrating the issue.

```html
<div class="selectable-blocks-provider-bid">
    <div class="day-item" v-for="(day, key) in days">
        {{ day }}
        <div class="hour-item" v-for="(hour, keyHour) in hours">
            {{ hour }}
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="available_block_for_bids[key]" :value="key+'-'+keyHour">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
    days: {
      0: "Sunday",
      1: "Monday",
      3: "Wednesday",
      5: "Friday",
      6: "Saturday",
    },
    hours: {
      0:"Early Morning",
      1:"Late Morning",
      2:"Early Afternoon",
      3:"Late Afternoon",
      4:"Early Evening",
      5:"Late Evening",
    },
    available_block_for_bids: {},
  },
  created() {
      let vm = this;
    _.each(vm.days, (item, key) => {

      vm.available_block_for_bids[key] = [];

    });
  }


});
```

Comment: It needs a little explanation. What is the issue you want to fix? That the checkbox overlays the text or that it doesn't appear to update the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
created() {
  let vm = this;
  _.each(vm.days, (item, key) => {

    vm.$set(vm.available_block_for_bids, key, []);

  });
}
```

Comment: Now that I see it, that's in the "Common Gotchas", right? About assigning values to an array by key. Thank you so much!

Comment: @dacastro4 Yep. Its one of the change detection caveats.